# How to properly use stacknavigator and drawernavigator in Expo

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am developing react native app with expo.

I am new to development in react native.

Anyone can please explain me how to properly use the navigation nested?

In this example, i am importing SearchList on my main page. It works ok!, But inside the searchlist i want to move to another pages and so on.

Using stackNavigator it may works, but i dont know how to do this when i am using the drawerNavigator.

```
   import SearchList from './Searches/search';

   const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
      Home:{
        screen:HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          header: null
        }
      },
      Info:{
        screen:SearchList
      },
    },{
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        drawerType: 'slide',
        contentComponent: Page2ComponentExample,
        drawerBackgroundColor: '#4eb6ce'
    });

    export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigatorExample);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a stack navigator for SearchList

```js
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator({
  SearchList: {
    screen: SearchList,
  },
  Details: {
    screen: Details,
  },
});
```

And after that just use the stack in your drawer

```js
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen:HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  Info:{
    screen: SearchStack //here
  },
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  drawerType: 'slide',
  contentComponent: Page2ComponentExample, 
  drawerBackgroundColor: '#4eb6ce'
});
```

Comment: I tried as the way you said, but now i am not able to see a back button in my second screens. do you know why? it shows a white background only in header

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to mention secondary navigation name instead of screen name. Let me give you an example.

```
const myDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: YOUR_HOME },
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.75
  }
)

const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  SplashScreen: {
    screen: SplashScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  SomeName: {
    screen: myDrawerNavigator ,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
})
```

As per your requirement you can try putting one navigation in another. Anyway it deems fit.

Comment: Yes! this is perfect. I don't know why it is downvoted